# Tableau: how to make a count if in a for loop?

Tags: tableau-api, countif

I'm just starting off Tableau and would like to do a count if in a for loop.

I have the following variables:

- City
- User
- Round: takes values of either A or B
- Amount

I would like to have a countif function that shows how many users received any positive amount in both round A and round B in a given city.

In my dashboard, each row represents a city, and I would like to have a column that shows the total number of users in each city that received amounts in both rounds.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can go for a simple solution that works.

1. Create a calculated field called "Positive Rounds per User" using the below formula:

// counts the number of unique rounds that had positive amounts per user in a city

{ FIXED [User], [City]: COUNTD(IIF([Amount]>0, [Round], NULL))}

2. You can use the above to create another calculated field called "unique users":

// unique number of users that have 2 in "Positive Rounds per User" field

COUNTD(IIF([Positive Rounds per User]=2, [User], NULL))

You can combine the calculation of 1 and 2 into one but it gets complex to read so better to split them up

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! In the data, a user can have 2 observations with both of them in round A. From my understanding ( and from applying your solution), your code include those as well. Is there a way to make sure that we only capture those users with positive amounts in round A and B? Thanks again, i appreciate it

Comment: Yes, you are right. If a user has raised money in round A twice in the same city then it will count it once only. We are only counting positive amount (thus, [Amount]>0 in the first calculated field). Only count if the round of amount is greater than 0. I assume positive amount in this context means greater than 0